# Play 2.4 How to intercept requests before it reach actions of a controller?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I want to intercept and validate authentication header of requests before it reach actions of a controller and check whether the header is valid or not. If it's valid then I will let the action resolve it, but if isn't I will redirect the user to the login page or send 403 error.

How can I achieve this in Play 2.4?

Comment: You may use [Action composition](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaActionsComposition) if you want check several actions, or [Filters](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaHttpFilters)

Comment: I tried Filters, but import play.filters can't be resolved.
Do you know why?

Comment: Have you added dependencies to build.sbt (libraryDependencies ++= Seq(... filters ...)

Comment: I've add filters to build.sbt. Still the same error.

Comment: why  `import play.filters`? May be `import play.api.mvc.Filter`

Comment: Your question is very broad, show us what did you try, and also what errors it did, otherwise we can just only blindly shoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [ALEX GARIBAY's blog](http://alexgaribay.com/2014/06/16/authentication-in-play-framework-using-java/).
Finally, I can perform authentication before a request reach an action by extending **Security.Authenticator**.

```
package models;
import play.mvc.Http;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.mvc.Security;

public class ActionAuthenticator extends Security.Authenticator {
    @Override
    public String getUsername(Http.Context ctx) {
        String token = getTokenFromHeader(ctx);
        if (token != null) {
            return token;   
        }

        //null if unauthorized
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Result onUnauthorized(Http.Context context) {
        return super.onUnauthorized(context);
    }

    private String getTokenFromHeader(Http.Context ctx) {
        String[] authTokenHeaderValues = ctx.request().headers().get("X-AUTH-TOKEN");
        if ((authTokenHeaderValues != null) && (authTokenHeaderValues.length == 1) && (authTokenHeaderValues[0] != null)) {
            return authTokenHeaderValues[0];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then I can annotate an action that require authentication like this.

```
@Security.Authenticated(ActionAuthenticator.class)
public Result authenticate() {
    return ok("Authenticated");
}
```

**ActionAuthenticator** will perform authentication inside **getUsername** and return an username if the authentication is valid and return null if its invalid.